# How to use ros::service::call()

Tags: ros-melodic, rosservice, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to call a service in code. The command line form is "rosservice call /move_base_node/clear_costmaps".

It has type std_srvs/Empty

There is function ros::service::call(const std::string &service_name, Service &service ) (documentation can be found [here](https://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1service.html#a763d311a7ac4c5909dee2c6bd060bfb6))

I am unsure what to put in the Service arg field

ros::service::call("/move_base_node/clear_costmaps", ??)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358746/how-to-use-ros::service::call()/) by [bevilllmen23](https://answers.ros.org/users/57375/bevilllmen23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this [rosservice](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial.

```
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/move_base_node/clear_costmaps");
  std_srvs::Empty srv;
  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Success!");
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service move_base_node/clear_costmaps");
    return 1;
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) with karma: 257 on 2020-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bevilllmen23](https://answers.ros.org/users/57375/bevilllmen23/) on 2020-08-06**:
Thank you, from this I was able to do
`std_srvs::Empty srv;`
`ros::service::call("/move_base_node/clear_costmaps", srv);`